# Font size display issue in iphone4 and 5 landscape view

Tags: html, media-queries

when i see the anchor text font in iphone 4 & 5 in landscape view. it is bigger then as compare to original size? but it is fine with portrait and i am using media query:

Please suggest???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css and the font sizes should not adjust for iOS devices:

```
* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Source: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind support... Detroit

Comment: this works, but i would recommend -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% instead